# The order of fetches in Session.run() when ambiguous dependencies exist

Tags: tensorflow

Wondering in what order the fetches in `Session.run()` are executed when ambiguous dependencies exist.

For example

`sess.run([self.train_op, self.sparsity_op, self.summary_op], feed_dict=feed_dict)`

where the `self.train_op` computes the gradients and updates weights, `self.sparsity_op` sets small weights to zeros, and `self.summary_op` write the sparsity of weights to file for tensorboard visualization.
Typically, there is no explicit dependency between `train_op` and `sparsity_op`, which means setting smaller weights to zeros either before or after weight updating are both logically correct but numerically different.

The question is: 
Will the fetches execute in the order of `self.train_op, self.sparsity_op, self.summary_op`? Why? And if not, how can I ensure the order?

Does the order of `self.train_op, self.sparsity_op, self.summary_op` in the list affect the order of execution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetches are executed in order of the list.  List or tuple fetches are stored as a list [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/client/session.py#L338), and results are built [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/client/session.py#L348).  So, I think there is no intentional re-order of fetche executions by the order of fetches.